# iPhone:Twitter Integration with HTTP Code 401 error

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I am using Twitter Integration using **MGTwitterengine** , **SAOAuthTwitterengine** in my app 
and I am successfully login in Twitter but not tweeted in Twitter its display **error like Request 85ABBA42-ABF6-46A8-9E36-6AA606E23C5A failed with error: Error Domain=HTTP Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 401.)"** and All Settings are successfully set in Twitter Developer Account like read,write and direct messages access permission etc so please solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you user iOS 5 inbuilt twitter functionality. Its so easy to integrate your app with twitter.

[You may refer this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TWTweetSheetViewControllerClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010943)

Comment: b'coz I want to develop till upto ios 4.2